# Is is possible to create a "signature" for a piece of JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Bear with me, I may have asked this question in a botched way.

So I need some JavaScript code that creates a signature of JavaScript that is stored in a string.

Here is an example:

```
presignature = "<script>alert("test")</script>;
```

I need this JavaScript code that is stored in **presignature** to be made into signature.
I was thinking I could just keep on replacing the string with common uses of javascript (like changing "alert" to "a").

Any clues or tips?

Comment: What do you understand as being “a signature”? (PS: Your code isn't valid javascript, check your quotes)

Answer (score 6):

Not a signature, however a [Content Security Policy](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/security/content-security-policy/) allows you to whitelist JavaScript for execution in your page 
by including a [SHA-256, SHA-384 or SHA-512](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-2) hash.

e.g. to allow `<script>alert('Hello, world.');</script>` you would include the following HTTP response header:

```
Content-Security-Policy: script-src 'sha256-sha256-qznLcsROx4GACP2dm0UCKCzCG-HiZ1guq6ZZDob_Tng='
```

Anything not matching would not be executed by [supported browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=contentsecuritypolicy).

You can also use this to find out the expected hash of a script in development by opening development tools in Chrome and examining error messages on any mismatch.

It depends what you're trying to acheive - would a hash value be enough, or do you actually require a signature?

Answer (score 2):

A snippit of javascript is a string, so it can be passed to a crypto library to get signed just like any other string.

Try googling "`javascript crypto library`" and see if you like any of the libraries that come up. Any crypto library will have signature functionality.